# Rasa entities extraction which appears to be similar for slot filling via forms. How to extract name of partner and name of customer in a form?

Tags: rasa-nlu

Actually I am creating a form which has **7 slots** in it namely : **customer name , partner name , license type ,  max users , max developers and project name**. While creating the intent with the entities mentioned in the brackets  I have created it like below :
[intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLx0J.png)

So now as the **customer name and partner name is appears like similar entity as both are names** the model struggles to differentiate and accept the entity. Though I define the intents separately it does not work. It takes in the customer name but while recognizing the partner name it does not take that input name as partner name entity and asks for the same slot rpeatedly. Similarly max_users intent is recognized but the model again struggles to recognize max_devs next to max_users entity as both are numbers. How to deal with this problem ? Is **entity roles** concept applicable here ? If yes please give an **ellaborated example** with all files included : nlu , domain , actions , stories , rules. If not please find me another solution with elaborated explanation.

This is how I have defined my slots :
[slots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZxYa.png)

Let me attach the interactive shell snapshots :
[interactive shell1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAoia.png)
[interactive shell2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z8Fw.png)
It repeatedly asks for my partner name but does not recognize the name though it asks me to mark the entity.

Lastly if the form is without the slots partner name and max developers it works perfectly fine. But when I include these two entities in the form I am not at able to find any solution anywhere as resources regarding this issue is limited.

1. I tried having separate intents for each of the slots for easy extraction of the entities. But it didn't work.
2. I tried including spacy classifier to extract entities when the model was struggling with DIETClassifier. Also it didn't work.
3. I tried adding more examples in training data and increasing the epochs also it didn't work.
4. I tried adapting roles and groups concept here but was left with limited resources in google which was also old versioned with different syntaxes. I couldn't even try achieving it.
5. I really want my model to recognize the customer name and partner name and store it in respected slots. Also it should happen for max_users and max_developers.